# Double inverting symbolic

Tags: matlab

When I ran a simple exercise of integration of defined functions as below,

```
clear all;
syms z tau;
deltav=tau^(1/(3*z))-tau^(1/(4*z));
deltax=1/(0.5+12*z)*(tau^(1/(3*z))-tau^(1/(4*z)));
a=1;
b=9;
tau=0.5;
mu_vx=int(deltav*deltax,a,b);
mu_x2=int(deltax^2,a,b);
ratio=double(mu_vx/mu_x2);
```

I got error message from MATLAB by saying "??? Error using ==> mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: DOUBLE cannot convert the input expression into
a double array.If the input expression contains a symbolic variable, use the VPA
function instead."

So I plug in the expression of "deltav" and "deltax" in to integration, and run

```
clear all;
syms z tau;
deltav=tau^(1/(3*z))-tau^(1/(4*z));
deltax=1/(0.5+12*z)*(tau^(1/(3*z))-tau^(1/(4*z)));
a=1;
b=9;
tau=0.5;
mu_vx=int((tau^(1/(3*z))-tau^(1/(4*z)))*1/(0.5+12*z)*(tau^(1/(3*z))-   tau^(1/(4*z))),a,b);
mu_x2=int((1/(0.5+12*z)*(tau^(1/(3*z))-tau^(1/(4*z))))^2,a,b);
ratio=double(mu_vx/mu_x2)
```

It works this time. I wonder how I should make the first way work without plugging the long expression. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a `solve` is necessary to find a explicit solution

```
mu_vx=int(solve(deltav*deltax),a,b);
mu_x2=int(solve(deltax^2),a,b);
ratio=double(mu_vx/mu_x2);
```

Comment: I have tried your answer. It does not work either by mu_vx=int(solve(deltav*deltax),a,b); or by mu_vx=solve(int(deltav*deltax,a,b));

Comment: With Matlab 2013a I get the result `1`